# Set Root View In App delegate with View Hierachy

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to be able to manually set the root view controller in app delegate intact with it's view hierarchy

My View Controller Hierarchy is

- TabBarController

  - UINavigationController

    - FirstViewController

      - **DetailedViewController** (I want to show this view)

Currently what I do is

```
  DetailedViewController *vc = (DetailedViewController *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedViewController"];
    [self.window setRootViewController:vc];
    [vc performSelector:@selector(setup:) withObject:section];
```

which obviously ignores the hierarchy and therefore when the app loads, I dont have the nav bar nor the tab bar.

So I tried this

```
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabController"];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

    DetailedViewController *vc = (DetailedViewController *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedViewController"];

    UINavigationController *navController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavController"];
    [navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

But using this code I can view **FirstViewController** and not the **DetailedViewController**

Comment: Why don't you assign detail view controller as root in storyboard along with using all this hierarchy stuff?

Comment: do you mean without* the hierarchy stuff? It's because without the nav bar and the tab bar the user wont be able to navigate within the app

Comment: I know, then why would you want to set detail controller as root?

Comment: I dont want to set detail view as "Root", What I am trying to do is when the user taps on a notification, the app opens with the detail view (with data relevant to the tapped notification)

Comment: Well if you want to maintain hierarchy on notification, you have to manually setup to push detail controller from first controller IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Your view hirarchy is such that 
You have tabbar that has navcontroller with a rootview of firstviewcontroller so this code add firstview as rootView

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabController"];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

FrstViewController *firstView = (FirstViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

    UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstview]
    self.tabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController,nil]

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

When the first we loads in **viewDidload** of it push detailviewcontroller

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
DetailedViewController *vc = (DetailedViewController *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController vc];
}
```